# Kubeadm join not working with the hostname of the device

Tags: kubernetes

I have initiated master using the hostname instead of ip address like below:

```
sudo kubeadm init --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=device1.local
```

Although I am using hostname instead of ip address, the token it generated contains ip address but it should contain hostname.

```
kubeadm join --token 2083f8.06a02c04e6d63e1e 192.168.1.2:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:e08f6f4fccf9cc7341e3eca040f4437de397a4347a4bdeb1cf354b440cdcc3ee
```

I used the above token on other node which I want to add but replaced the ip address with hostname `device1.local` and ran the command but it showed below error:

```
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://device1.local:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: dial tcp: lookup device1.local on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host]
```

Both the device can ping each other using hostname. Also if I try to access `https://pi1.local:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info` I get some info about the cluster on browser but kubeadm is not able to find it.

How can I use hostname instead of using the ip address. How can I make `kubeadm init` to generate token which contains hostname.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It actually using a hostname for discovery - `lookup device1.local on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host` - that means that it cannot resolve host `device1.local` using DNS server `192.168.1.1:53`.

So, you doing it right, just check that hostname which you using as `apiserver-advertise-address`, which has to be an apiserver hostname, resolvable on all your nodes, by `nslookup device1.local`, as example.

Comment: Thankyou. What do you mean by `resolvable on all your nodes, by nslookup device1.local`. I can ping hostnames of all the nodes from each nodes

Comment: K8s trying to lookup a hostname `device1.local` using DNS `192.168.1.1:53`. So check that this DNS returning a correct result for your hostname.

Comment: But I have not setup any local DNS. Do I need to setup a local DNS server for this. I thought simply using the hostname will work.

Comment: I think you can just add a record to host files on all your nodes like that: `echo "$ip_or_your_api_server $apiserver-advertise-address_value" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`. Do not forget to replace variables to your values. And also check DNS settings in the same file. That is the common case when the application cannot resolve a hostname, but you can ping it or `host` command works:)

Comment: Thankyou I'll definitely try it. But what value should i use for this variable `$apiserver-advertise-address_value`.

Comment: IP address of you api server, which has a hostname `device1.local` in your example.